# winload.efi not found but can boot through UEFI settings

Tags: windows-10, boot

I just reinstalled Windows 10 1809 on my laptop and this message appears when I try to boot up my system. (I found the image online. It's close enough)

[image]

The other settings on the screen did not work. "Recovery Mode", "Start Up Settings" and "Try Again" just came back to this page after a black flash.

But when I try "ESC" to enter my BIOS settings, and then "Save and Continue", it can boot into Windows no problem. And I can verify I do have the file when I check in Explorer and I've logged in afterwards.

The problem always happen when I turn on my laptop. Anyone knows what could be done to fix this?

---

EDIT:

Diskpart

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.17763.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: DESKTOP-PU5U9TH

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    119 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1     D   LENOVO       NTFS   Partition    891 GB  Healthy
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    513 MB  Healthy    System

DISKPART>
```

---

EDIT:

[image]

Regarding my EFI partition on my second drive. It is Ubuntu's GRUB installation. Everything Windows has installed is in my C Drive. The Windows installation should not have touched elsewhere, since my prompt in the installation was "fresh install" and not "install along other OS". (I forgot the exact word phrasing, but that's how it was.)

I also lost my ability to boot from GRUB, since the bootloader in my C Drive didn't have the record of where GRUB is.

---

Edit:

EFI Drive File Tree:

```
Z:\>tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is CA10-DC31
Z:.
└───EFI
    ├───Microsoft
    │   ├───Boot
    │   │   │   BCD
    │   │   │   boot.stl
    │   │   │   bootmgfw.efi
    │   │   │   bootmgr.efi
    │   │   │   memtest.efi
    │   │   │   winsipolicy.p7b
    │   │   │   kd_02_10df.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_10ec.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_1137.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_14e4.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_15b3.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_1969.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_19a2.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_1af4.dll
    │   │   │   kd_02_8086.dll
    │   │   │   kd_07_1415.dll
    │   │   │   kd_0C_8086.dll
    │   │   │   kdstub.dll
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───bg-BG
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───cs-CZ
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───da-DK
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───de-DE
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───el-GR
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───en-GB
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───en-US
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───es-ES
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───es-MX
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───et-EE
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───fi-FI
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───fr-CA
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───fr-FR
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───hr-HR
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───hu-HU
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───it-IT
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───ja-JP
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───ko-KR
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───lt-LT
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───lv-LV
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───nb-NO
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───nl-NL
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───pl-PL
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───pt-BR
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───pt-PT
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───qps-ploc
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───ro-RO
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───ru-RU
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───sk-SK
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───sl-SI
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───sr-Latn-RS
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───sv-SE
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───tr-TR
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───uk-UA
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───zh-CN
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───zh-TW
    │   │   │       bootmgfw.efi.mui
    │   │   │       bootmgr.efi.mui
    │   │   │       memtest.efi.mui
    │   │   │
    │   │   ├───Fonts
    │   │   │       chs_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       cht_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       jpn_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       kor_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       malgunn_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       malgun_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       meiryon_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       meiryo_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       msjhn_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       msjh_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       msyhn_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       msyh_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       segmono_boot.ttf
    │   │   │       segoen_slboot.ttf
    │   │   │       segoe_slboot.ttf
    │   │   │       wgl4_boot.ttf
    │   │   │
    │   │   └───Resources
    │   │       │   bootres.dll
    │   │       │
    │   │       └───en-US
    │   │               bootres.dll.mui
    │   │
    │   └───Recovery
    │           BCD
    │
    └───Boot
            bootx64.efi
```

---

### After trying the bootloader EFI fix. Same as before.

This time, I've included the actual screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but I don't understand why.

I have 2 drives:

- C: SSD (Drive 1)
- D: HDD (Drive 2)

I used to have my MBR records (EFI) on my D drive. I tried reinstalling Windows a few times without removing my EFI partition, and the results were the same.

Once I removed that partition and reinstalled Windows fresh on my C drive. The problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions.

**Startup repair**

- Run *Settings > Update & security > Recovery > Advanced startup > Restart now*
- Go to *Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Automatic repair*
- Follow the instructions of the Recovery Wizard.

**Repair the EFI Bootloader**

- Run `diskpart`
- In diskpart, list the partitions on the disks:

  ```
  list volume
  ```
- Find a partition labeled ESP or EFI with a size which is usually 100/500 MB
- Select this partition:

  ```
  select volume 2
  ```
- Assign a drive letter to the partition:

  ```
  assign letter=Z
  ```
- Exit diskpart:

  ```
  exit
  ```
- To re-create the bootloader by copying the boot files from the
  Windows directory, start an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) and run the command:

  ```
  bcdboot C:\Windows /s Z: /f ALL
  ```
- Reboot.

To remove the disk-letter Z:

- Enter Disk Management
- Right-click the partition named Z
- Select the option of *Change Drive Letter and Paths*
- Click *Remove*
- Click OK

**Missing UEFI partition**

If your computer does not have a partition labeled ESP or EFI with
a size which is usually 100/500 MB, then you have probably migrated
the disk from an older computer that does not use EFI.

To create that partition do:

- Enter Disk Management and ensure that there is enough unallocated space
  on the disk, say 2 GB
- If there is not enough unallocated space, resize the Windows partition
  to reduce it by 2 GB
- Redo Startup Repair as above.

Comment: Automatic Repair doesn't work. Regarding the output of diskpart, it is now in my question, `list volume` does not list anything with `EFI`. Another thing I wish to add, is I can boot into Windows if I go through UEFI. So I'm wondering if `winload.efi` just can't be read the first time around.

Comment: Is your disk MBR or GPT? You don't seem to have any UEFI boot partition! This might be your problem, so I will add a part for it.

Comment: I'm not too sure, but this laptop is just 3 years old. And I reinstalled Windows on an empty SSD. I've added my disk manager screenshot to my question. Because it does say Boot in my first partition. And regarding my EFI partition on my second drive. It is Ubuntu's GRUB.

Comment: This does show an EFI partition, but evidently something is wrong with it. You might want to, as written above, to assign it a drive letter and use `bcdboot` to update the files. I suggest having good backups first, and perhaps also ensure that you have a [Windows boot media](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html), just in case.

Comment: That EFI partition is Linux GRUB. Since I've reinstalled Windows on an empty SSD, I've lost the ability to boot from that partition. And that partition shouldn't be where Windows bootloader is. But that doesn't answer the question though, since Windows bootloader should have worked, otherwise, I wouldn't be typing this comment out on this laptop. Right? 

Comment: All I can say is that there is a problem with the boot code. You might assign the drive-letter and take a look inside the partition to see if Windows is there.

Comment: I saw your edit and all seems to be there. Very very strange. Beside `bcdboot`, you may also try the free version of [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to fix UEFI boot.

Comment: I've tried the bcdboot method. Please see my edit. Still quite strange? The EFI partition is in my second drive, but my BIOS was trying to boot into the first drive. I saw this in the boot order settings, listing the model number of the drives.

Comment: I just checked MS Docs, it seems my problem has passed the BCD stage?: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/img-boot-sequence

Comment: Try the command `bcdboot C:\windows /s Z: /f UEFI`. If not, the only last advice I can think of is to boot Windows from an installation USB, enter Repair, and do Startup Repair from there. If nothing works, let me know in addition if Linux was installed after or before Windows?